# How to generate formula field value?

Tags: apex

I just wanted to create an SObject (Account) as a placeholder.

here's my code:

```
Account acc = new Account();

acc.ContactId = contact.Id;
acc.Name = 'Sample Account';

System.debug(acc.ContactName__c); // Output is null. This field is a formula. Contact.FirstName & " " & Contact.LastName
```

Is there a way to generate the value for that formula without inserting the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalculation of cross object formulas is not supported. There is no programmatic, generic way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Just need to confirm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wondering how to calculate a formula without "having the object inserted", take to transactions:

```Apex
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Contact__c = contact.Id;
acc.Name = 'Sample Account';
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
insert acc;
acc = [SELECT ContactName__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: acc.Id];
System.debug(acc.ContactName__c);
Database.rollback(sp);
List<Account> l = [SELECT ContactName__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: acc.Id];
System.assertEquals(0, l.size());
```

Comment: That's great. But kinda slows the process.